# Converting from WAV to MP3 using WMP 12

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, wav

Hopefully this is a really dumb question, but I can't find the answer:

Using WMP 12, bundled with Win64 Home Premium. I have a big music library in WAV format for use on my home stereo system.

Sometimes I want to convert some of the material to MP3 format for use on my portable player. Not ripping or burning - just want to take an existing WAV file and create an MP3 copy on my HDD.

Cannot find an option in WMP to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WMP isn't a music converter and hence doesn't offer such an option. But you could use a third-party tool such as [LameXP](http://lamexp.sourceforge.net/) for converting to MP3.

Comment: Thanks - I actually discovered I have some other software on my machine that does do that.